# Formatting listview row items on Selection

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView a row of which contains a couple of TextViews, an image and a button.
My requirement is that when a row item is selected, the Text Style and color of the TextViews and the background drawable of the button should change.

I am not sure of how to do this.

**Questions/Assumptions/What I think:**

1. Will having a state drawable for every item in the row work here? I have read some where that ListView has problems when there are focusable components present in its row.
2. Should this be done programmatically? Like should I intercept the itemSelected/onRowFocus or equivalent method of the ListView object and make the necessary changes?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I asked a similar question [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c8616d86be20f0ec/1dda221dfc9accea?lnk=gst&q=Samuh#1dda221dfc9accea). Hope that helps!